# switch_to.window() works fine on Win10 but returns unable to locate window on Linux

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Just as in title, while testing code on Win10 everything works just fine but after trying to run code on Linux I get `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: unable to locate window: undefined`.

I'm using geckodriver 0.31 on both OS but firefox version differs (68.12.0esr on Linux and 91.13.0esr on Win). May that be the reason for this error, or is there something else that may cause the problem?

`print(self.driver.window_handles)` returns list of 2 handles.

Code below:

```
def close_additional_popups(self):
        while len(self.driver.window_handles) > 1:
            windows = self.driver.window_handles
            self.driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1])
            check_if_its_embargo_popup_frame = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='WorkAreaFrame1popup']").get_attribute('title')
            if check_if_its_embargo_popup_frame == 'Embargo regulations':
                self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
                WebDriverWait(self.driver, TIMEOUT_100).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
                self.driver.switch_to.frame('WorkAreaFrame1popup')
                self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//b[contains(text(), 'No')]").click()
                sleep(3)
            else:  
                self.driver.close()
            self.driver.switch_to.window(windows[0])
        self.switch_to_WorkAreaFrame()
```

EDIT: forgot to mention that on linux I'm running executable made with pyinstaller(don't know if that is useful info though)

Comment: The geckodriver for windows and Linux is different, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases.

Comment: @dudulu I'm already aware of this and I'm using correct versions for both os's. Rest of code work fine but switching between windows is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used older version of geckodriver (0.29.1) and selenium (3.14.1) and it helped out.